# Fuzzing framework needed for ISO 14443

Tags: fuzzing

which fuzzing framework would be suitable for ISO 14443 protocol?

I have looked into sulley framework but that is out of maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Jinesh - while doing research on fuzzing and frameworks, I noticed Boofuzz which is a fork of Sulley's framework. It is relatively more current and might be an option for you. You can read more here https://stackarmor.com/managing-vulnerabilities-using-fuzz-testing-or-fuzzing-as-part-of-secdevops/